# DataGrid and button: event handler for click not called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, click, wpfdatagrid

I have a `StackPanel` with a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataSet` in it and a `Grid` below the `DataGrid` at the bottom of the `StackPanel`. The `Grid` holds a `Button` which I want to use to update the `DataAdapter` associated with the `DataSet` after the user changed the content of the `DataGrid`.

This mostly works as expected, but not always.

My expectation is that the eventhandler is called whenever I click the button. This does work if I change an existing line in the data grid and then click the button, or if I enter values in the last (empty) line of the grid, then press enter and finally click the button. If I enter values in the last line of the grid and do not press enter, clicking the button results in a new (empty) line at the bottom of the data grid and the eventhandler is *not* called. Only by clicking it a second time the event handler is called. Why is this? Can I change this?

My first suspicion was that the `DataSet`somehow needs to be informed about new data, but if I add a new line, press enter and add a second new line then the button click also does not result in a call to the event handler, which implies that my suspicion does not explain the behaviour.

This is using Visual Studio Express 2012

Here is the `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="AppVer0._01.ProducerWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Producer" Height="300" Width="300">
  <StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding producer}"    
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Name="producerDataGrid"
              />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Name="buttonUpdate" Click="buttonUpdate_Click_1">Aktualisieren</Button>
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

(I plan to add more buttons, so the grid has some more columns) The code behind (for `Window) defines the binding as follows:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
// ...
// load data from adapter into dataset
// 
this.DataContext = ds;
```

and there is, of course, the eventhandler defined.

**Edit:** In case that matters, the window is called as a dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to change the behaviour I described with the help of an article on [this MS page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx). I added a handler to the MouseDownEvent of the button which will be called even when the `e.Handled` attribute has been set to true, as follows:

```
buttonUpdate.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent,
        (RoutedEventHandler)buttonUpdate_ClickAlwaysCalled, true);
```

The `true` at the end does the trick, and the handler which has been assigned in the XAML is now no langer called at all (so the new handler seems to get called first and somehow magically sets `event.Handled` to `true`, but I don't know whether I can rely on this. Since calling the update function twice does no harm this is fine for me). I'm not sure whether this is a good way of doing this, but it does work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check and see if DataGrid is in edit mode or not.

Handle these two events in your dataGrid: [BeginningEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.beginningedit.aspx) and [CellEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending.aspx) (or maybe in your case [RowEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.roweditending.aspx))

define this property `public bool IsInEditMode;` and :

```
void dg_BeginningEdit(object sender, BeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    IsInEditMode=true;
}

void dg_CellEditEnding(object sender, CellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    IsInEditMode=false;
}
```

Now you can determine when you are in edit mode, when the Button is pressed:

```
 void buttonUpdate_Click_1(...)
 {
      if (IsInEditMode)
       {
           producerDataGrid.CommitEdit();
       }
  }
```

see [CommitEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402940.aspx) method. We call it to end edit.

Comment: Thank you. While this does not solve the problem (the button click handler is still not entered) it does shed some light on it. The button click event seems to get lost if the datagrid is in edit mode, but instead seems to produce somehow a RowEditEnding event. So the coding you suggested for the button click handler is never executed. Is there some button event which is triggered befor the click event, to which I could add that code?

Comment: @Thomas Maybe you can handle PreviewMouseButtonDown of the Button and in that event, call :  `if (IsInEditMode){
           producerDataGrid.CommitEdit();
       }`

Comment: I gave this a try, too, but, the PreviewMouseButtonDown event handler is also not called in the situation I described. I upvoted, though, since you led me on a helpful track, thank you.